# React Native - Navigator callbacks

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

When  I am using navigator, how do we hook into 'willFocus' and 'didFocus' events?
I am  trying below code:

```
this.refs.sideBarNavigator.navigationContext.addListener('willFocus', this._navigatorWillFocus);
this.refs.sideBarNavigator.navigationContext.addListener('didFocus', this._navigatorDidFocus);
```

but the callbacks don't seem to be called when a scene is popped, pushed or replaced.

I am not sure if I am getting navigationContext correctly.

Comment: you must hook them before Navigator rendered , accessing from refs means you're doing after render. put u r code before render( in renderScene call back if you have access)

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example? It's still not clear where I can obtain navigationContext from in your answer.

Comment: renderScene has navigator ref :) , here is an example  https://github.com/exponentjs/ex-navigator/blob/master/ExNavigator.js#L71

Comment: Awesome! That helped a ton! Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should elevate the comment to an answer?